# Understanding bootlog load address

Tags: ida, firmware, mips

I was looking at the bootlog for the WAG160N found here: https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/linksys/wag160n and I wanted to clarify how the booting works.

*Boot Address 0xbfc00000

Total memory used by CFE:  0x80401000 - 0x80528800 (1210368)*

Why is the boot address not within in total memory used range (0x8040100-0x80528800) of CFE? If I understand correctly 0xbfc00000 is already a virtual memory address.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MIPS [memory mapping](http://www.johnloomis.org/microchip/pic32/memory/memory.html) is pretty peculiar. The virtual address `0xbfc00000` (in `kseg1`) corresponds to the physical address `0x1fc00000` and is likely in ROM. I suspect that the range 0x80401000 - 0x80528800  is in RAM (`kseg0`), so it's natural the addresses don't match. To know more you will probably need to read the processor's datasheet and/or board schematics to figure out where exactly and how much ROM and RAM are present.